# Cannot connect to AWS SQL database - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<endpoint>' (111)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a remote SQL database (RDS) on Amazon Web Services which I am attempting to connect to via the Linux terminal.

Having run the following command, substituting each value:

`sudo mysql -u <username> -h <endpoiont> -P <port> -p`

and then entered my password, I get the following error message:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<endpoint>' (111)`

This used to work up to a few weeks ago and I have not changed any of the AWS permissions and security settings since. I also changed the password since this error but this did not solve the problem.

My application itself **can** connect to the DB, only I cannot connect via the Linux terminal.

Some solutions that I have read related to making changes to local files but this SQL database is hosted on AWS, not on my local machine.

Any suggested solutions are welcome.

Comment: Code 111 is a MySQL server that is not running or is not bound to all interfaces, or you're being blocked by a firewall where *you* are (not by AWS security groups or network ACLs).

Comment: I think you are right, it did seem to be a network related issue as I tried again later on another network and all was fine. Thanks :)